# Scroll ListView inside VerticalPager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, vertical-scrolling

I am working on an app based on the `VerticalPager` implemented by Grantland Chew and available in [GitHub](https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager).

This class `extends ViewGroup` and Overrides all methods related to scrolling.

In one of the fragments I have a `ListView` and I need to be able to scroll it because some times the list is long. The problem is that whenever I try to do that it is the fragment who moves.

I have been trying to find a solution but it seems there is none. There are some times in which I'm able to scroll the list, but after pressing an element for a while and it doesn't always work.

How can I solve this? There's an `OnScrollListener` interface, maybe doing something with that?

Here's the code for "my" version of the class:

```
/**
 * This is a slightly modified version of the vertical pager by Grantland Chew: <br>
 * <a href="https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager">https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager</a>
 * <p>
 * Custom changes: <br>
 * 1) removed the code that shrinks the first page a little bit to make beginning of the next page visible. <br>
 * 2) onMeasure will better handle pages height (changed from MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED to MeasureSpec.EXACTLY). <br>
 * 3) added {@link VerticalPager#snapToPage(int, int)} method to request snap with a custom duration <br>
 * 4) added {@link VerticalPager#setPagingEnabled(boolean)} method to lock/unlock paging
 */
public class VerticalPager extends ViewGroup {

/**
 * Default page snap duration in milliseconds.
 */
public static final int PAGE_SNAP_DURATION_DEFAULT = 300;

/**
 * Instant page snap duration in milliseconds.
 */
public static final int PAGE_SNAP_DURATION_INSTANT = 1;

private boolean mIsPagingEnabled = true;

public static final String TAG = "VerticalPager";

private static final int INVALID_SCREEN = -1;
public static final int SPEC_UNDEFINED = -1;
private static final int TOP = 0;
private static final int BOTTOM = 1;

/**
 * The velocity at which a fling gesture will cause us to snap to the next screen
 */
private static final int SNAP_VELOCITY = 1000;

private int pageHeight;
private int measuredHeight;

private boolean mFirstLayout = true;

private int mCurrentPage;
private int mNextPage = INVALID_SCREEN;

private Scroller mScroller;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;

private int mTouchSlop;
private int mMaximumVelocity;

private float mLastMotionY;
private float mLastMotionX;

private final static int TOUCH_STATE_REST = 0;
private final static int TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING = 1;

private int mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;

private boolean mAllowLongPress;

private Set<OnScrollListener> mListeners = new HashSet<OnScrollListener>();

/**
 * Used to inflate the Workspace from XML.
 *
 * @param context
 *            The application's context.
 * @param attrs
 *            The attribtues set containing the Workspace's customization values.
 */
public VerticalPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

/**
 * Used to inflate the Workspace from XML.
 *
 * @param context
 *            The application's context.
 * @param attrs
 *            The attribtues set containing the Workspace's customization values.
 * @param defStyle
 *            Unused.
 */
public VerticalPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

/**
 * Initializes various states for this workspace.
 */
private void init(Context context) {
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext(), new DecelerateInterpolator());
    mCurrentPage = 0;

    final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
    mTouchSlop = configuration.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMaximumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the currently displayed page.
 *
 * @return The index of the currently displayed page.
 */
public int getCurrentPage() {
    return mCurrentPage;
}

/**
 * Sets the current page.
 *
 * @param currentPage
 */
void setCurrentPage(int currentPage) {
    mCurrentPage = Math.max(0, Math.min(currentPage, getChildCount()));
    scrollTo(getScrollYForPage(mCurrentPage), 0);
    invalidate();
}

public int getPageHeight() {
    return pageHeight;
}

// public void setPageHeight(int pageHeight) {
// this.pageHeightSpec = pageHeight;
// }

/**
 * Gets the value that getScrollX() should return if the specified page is the current page (and no other scrolling
 * is occurring). Use this to pass a value to scrollTo(), for example.
 *
 * @param whichPage
 * @return
 */
private int getScrollYForPage(int whichPage) {
    int height = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < whichPage; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
            height += child.getHeight();
        }
    }
    return height - pageHeightPadding();
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
        postInvalidate();
    } else if (mNextPage != INVALID_SCREEN) {
        mCurrentPage = mNextPage;
        mNextPage = INVALID_SCREEN;
        clearChildrenCache();
    }

}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // ViewGroup.dispatchDraw() supports many features we don't need:
    // clip to padding, layout animation, animation listener, disappearing
    // children, etc. The following implementation attempts to fast-track
    // the drawing dispatch by drawing only what we know needs to be drawn.

    final long drawingTime = getDrawingTime();
    // todo be smarter about which children need drawing
    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        drawChild(canvas, getChildAt(i), drawingTime);
    }

    for (OnScrollListener mListener : mListeners) {
        int adjustedScrollY = getScrollY() + pageHeightPadding();
        mListener.onScroll(adjustedScrollY);
        if (adjustedScrollY % pageHeight == 0) {
            mListener.onViewScrollFinished(adjustedScrollY / pageHeight);
        }
    }
}

int pageHeightPadding() {
    return ((getMeasuredHeight() - pageHeight) / 2);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    pageHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // getChildAt(i).measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(),
        // MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        // MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageHeight,
        // MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        getChildAt(i).measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }

    if (mFirstLayout) {
        scrollTo(getScrollYForPage(mCurrentPage), 0);
        mFirstLayout = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    measuredHeight = 0;

    final int count = getChildCount();
    int height;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
            height = pageHeight * (int) Math.ceil((double) child.getMeasuredHeight() / (double) pageHeight);
            height = Math.max(pageHeight, height);
            child.layout(0, measuredHeight, right - left, measuredHeight + height);
            measuredHeight += height;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(View child, Rect rectangle, boolean immediate) {
    int screen = indexOfChild(child);
    if (screen != mCurrentPage || !mScroller.isFinished()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean onRequestFocusInDescendants(int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    int focusableScreen;
    if (mNextPage != INVALID_SCREEN) {
        focusableScreen = mNextPage;
    } else {
        focusableScreen = mCurrentPage;
    }
    getChildAt(focusableScreen).requestFocus(direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchUnhandledMove(View focused, int direction) {
    if (direction == View.FOCUS_LEFT) {
        if (getCurrentPage() > 0) {
            snapToPage(getCurrentPage() - 1);
            return true;
        }
    } else if (direction == View.FOCUS_RIGHT) {
        if (getCurrentPage() < getChildCount() - 1) {
            snapToPage(getCurrentPage() + 1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchUnhandledMove(focused, direction);
}

@Override
public void addFocusables(ArrayList<View> views, int direction) {
    getChildAt(mCurrentPage).addFocusables(views, direction);
    if (direction == View.FOCUS_LEFT) {
        if (mCurrentPage > 0) {
            getChildAt(mCurrentPage - 1).addFocusables(views, direction);
        }
    } else if (direction == View.FOCUS_RIGHT) {
        if (mCurrentPage < getChildCount() - 1) {
            getChildAt(mCurrentPage + 1).addFocusables(views, direction);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (!mIsPagingEnabled)
        return false;

    /*
     * This method JUST determines whether we want to intercept the motion. If we return true, onTouchEvent will be
     * called and we do the actual scrolling there.
     */

    /*
     * Shortcut the most recurring case: the user is in the dragging state and he is moving his finger. We want to
     * intercept this motion.
     */
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) && (mTouchState != TOUCH_STATE_REST)) {
        return true;
    }

    final float y = ev.getY();
    final float x = ev.getX();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        /*
         * mIsBeingDragged == false, otherwise the shortcut would have caught it. Check whether the user has moved
         * far enough from his original down touch.
         */
            if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_REST) {
                checkStartScroll(x, y);
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Remember location of down touch
            mLastMotionX = x;
            mLastMotionY = y;
            mAllowLongPress = true;

        /*
         * If being flinged and user touches the screen, initiate drag; otherwise don't. mScroller.isFinished should
         * be false when being flinged.
         */
            mTouchState = mScroller.isFinished() ? TOUCH_STATE_REST : TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Release the drag
            clearChildrenCache();
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
            break;
    }

    /*
     * The only time we want to intercept motion events is if we are in the drag mode.
     */
    return mTouchState != TOUCH_STATE_REST;
}

/**
 * Enable or disable pages switching.
 *
 * @param enabled
 *            true - enable pages switching, false - disable.
 */
public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mIsPagingEnabled = enabled;
}

/**
 * @return true - if pages switching enabled, false - otherwise.
 */
public boolean isPagingEnabled() {
    return mIsPagingEnabled;
}

private void checkStartScroll(float x, float y) {
    /*
     * Locally do absolute value. mLastMotionX is set to the y value of the down event.
     */
    final int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(x - mLastMotionX);
    final int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(y - mLastMotionY);

    boolean xMoved = xDiff > mTouchSlop;
    boolean yMoved = yDiff > mTouchSlop;

    if (xMoved || yMoved) {

        if (yMoved) {
            // Scroll if the user moved far enough along the X axis
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
            enableChildrenCache();
        }
        // Either way, cancel any pending longpress
        if (mAllowLongPress) {
            mAllowLongPress = false;
            // Try canceling the long press. It could also have been
            // scheduled
            // by a distant descendant, so use the mAllowLongPress flag to
            // block
            // everything
            final View currentScreen = getChildAt(mCurrentPage);
            currentScreen.cancelLongPress();
        }
    }
}

void enableChildrenCache() {
    setChildrenDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    setChildrenDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true);
}

void clearChildrenCache() {
    setChildrenDrawnWithCacheEnabled(false);
}

public void hideKeyboard(){
    InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(BottomFragment.query.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    hideKeyboard();
    if (!mIsPagingEnabled)
        return false;

    if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
    }
    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(ev);

    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        /*
         * If being flinged and user touches, stop the fling. isFinished will be false if being flinged.
         */
            if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
                mScroller.abortAnimation();
            }

            // Remember where the motion event started
            mLastMotionY = y;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_REST) {
                checkStartScroll(y, x);
            } else if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING) {
                // Scroll to follow the motion event
                int deltaY = (int) (mLastMotionY - y);
                mLastMotionY = y;

                // Apply friction to scrolling past boundaries.
                final int count = getChildCount();
                if (getScrollY() < 0 || getScrollY() + pageHeight > getChildAt(count - 1).getBottom()) {
                    deltaY /= 2;
                }

                scrollBy(0, deltaY);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING) {
                final VelocityTracker velocityTracker = mVelocityTracker;
                velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000, mMaximumVelocity);
                int velocityY = (int) velocityTracker.getYVelocity();

                final int count = getChildCount();

                // check scrolling past first or last page?
                if (getScrollY() < 0) {
                    snapToPage(0);
                } else if (getScrollY() > measuredHeight - pageHeight) {
                    snapToPage(count - 1, BOTTOM, PAGE_SNAP_DURATION_DEFAULT);
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        final View child = getChildAt(i);
                        if (child.getTop() < getScrollY() && child.getBottom() > getScrollY() + pageHeight) {
                            // we're inside a page, fling that bitch
                            mNextPage = i;
                            mScroller.fling(getScrollX(), getScrollY(), 0, -velocityY, 0, 0, child.getTop(),
                                    child.getBottom() - getHeight());
                            invalidate();
                            break;
                        } else if (child.getBottom() > getScrollY() && child.getBottom() < getScrollY() + getHeight()) {
                            // stuck in between pages, oh snap!
                            if (velocityY < -SNAP_VELOCITY) {
                                snapToPage(i + 1);
                            } else if (velocityY > SNAP_VELOCITY) {
                                snapToPage(i, BOTTOM, PAGE_SNAP_DURATION_DEFAULT);
                            } else if (getScrollY() + pageHeight / 2 > child.getBottom()) {
                                snapToPage(i + 1);
                            } else {
                                snapToPage(i, BOTTOM, PAGE_SNAP_DURATION_DEFAULT);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (mVelocityTracker != null) {
                    mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                    mVelocityTracker = null;
                }
            }
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_REST;
    }

    return true;
}

private void snapToPage(final int whichPage, final int where, int duration) {

    enableChildrenCache();

    if(whichPage != 1){
        MainActivity.backCount = 0;
        MainActivity.isMainShowing = false;
    }

    boolean changingPages = whichPage != mCurrentPage;

    mNextPage = whichPage;

    View focusedChild = getFocusedChild();
    if (focusedChild != null && changingPages && focusedChild == getChildAt(mCurrentPage)) {
        focusedChild.clearFocus();
    }

    final int delta;
    if (getChildAt(whichPage).getHeight() <= pageHeight || where == TOP) {
        delta = getChildAt(whichPage).getTop() - getScrollY();
    } else {
        delta = getChildAt(whichPage).getBottom() - pageHeight - getScrollY();
    }

    mScroller.startScroll(0, getScrollY(), 0, delta, duration);
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Snap pager to the specified page with the default {@link VerticalPager#PAGE_SNAP_DURATION_DEFAULT} duration.
 *
 * @param whichPage
 *            Zero based index of the page.
 */
public void snapToPage(final int whichPage) {
    snapToPage(whichPage, TOP, PAGE_SNAP_DURATION_DEFAULT);
}

/**
 * Snap pager to the specified page.
 *
 * @param whichPage
 *            Zero based index of the page.
 * @param duration
 *            Duration in milliseconds of scrolling to the chosen page.
 */
public void snapToPage(final int whichPage, int duration) {
    snapToPage(whichPage, TOP, duration);
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    final SavedState state = new SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState());
    state.currentScreen = mCurrentPage;
    return state;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
    if (savedState.currentScreen != INVALID_SCREEN) {
        mCurrentPage = savedState.currentScreen;
    }
}

public void scrollUp() {
    if (mNextPage == INVALID_SCREEN && mCurrentPage > 0 && mScroller.isFinished()) {
        snapToPage(mCurrentPage - 1);
    }
}

public void scrollDown() {
    if (mNextPage == INVALID_SCREEN && mCurrentPage < getChildCount() - 1 && mScroller.isFinished()) {
        snapToPage(mCurrentPage + 1);
    }
}

public int getScreenForView(View v) {
    int result = -1;
    if (v != null) {
        ViewParent vp = v.getParent();
        int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (vp == getChildAt(i)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * @return True is long presses are still allowed for the current touch
 */
public boolean allowLongPress() {
    return mAllowLongPress;
}

public static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
    int currentScreen = -1;

    SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
        super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        currentScreen = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeInt(currentScreen);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SavedState(in);
        }

        public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SavedState[size];
        }
    };
}

public void addOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener) {
    mListeners.add(listener);
}

public void removeOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener listener) {
    mListeners.remove(listener);
}

/**
 * Implement to receive events on scroll position and page snaps.
 */
public static interface OnScrollListener {
    /**
     * Receives the current scroll X value. This value will be adjusted to assume the left edge of the first page
     * has a scroll position of 0. Note that values less than 0 and greater than the right edge of the last page are
     * possible due to touch events scrolling beyond the edges.
     *
     * @param scrollX
     *            Scroll X value
     */
    void onScroll(int scrollX);

    /**
     * Invoked when scrolling is finished (settled on a page, centered).
     *
     * @param currentPage
     *            The current page
     */
    void onViewScrollFinished(int currentPage);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue.

For those of you who find this interesting, I modified the `checkStartScroll(float x, float y)` method of the `VerticalPager` class to track the **position** of the user's finger when performing the scroll.

Here's the code:

```
private void checkStartScroll(float x, float y){
    [...]
    if (yMoved){
        if (currentPage == pageWithTheListView){
            // if not scrolling the ListView
            if (mLastMotionY < 420){
                mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_SCROLLING;
                enableChildrenCache();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not use scrollbar, use header for list view.

1. Create a view (xml)
2. Inflate in code and addheader of listview.

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);

listView.addHeaderView(headerView);

I hope it will help.

Comment: could you please explain how adding a header can help?

Comment: This will not work untill set adapter is called on list view atleast once